# How to play specific video files through python script based on passed integer

Tags: raspbian, python, video, pi-3b+

I have an oddly specific problem, though aren't they all? I have a RPi 3B+ on stretch that I'm trying to boot into a python script that I've written that receives an integer and passes it to two Arduino slaves. At the same time, I'm trying to have a video open, play, and close when finished based on the integer entered.

I've looked into both opencv and oxmplayer solutions, but I didn't get very far with other (I'm missing some opencv dependency and oxmplayer refuses to download).

Here is the script I've written to load on boot up:

```
import serial
import serial.tools.list_ports
import subprocess

def getArduinos():
    ports = [
        p.device
        for p in serial.tools.list_ports.comports()
        if '9025' == str(p.vid) ]
    return ports

ports = getArduinos()

#get the command from the user
command = input("input the command 1 - 5 (5 to quit): ")
while(command != 5):
    ser = serial.Serial(ports[0], 9600)
    ser2 = serial.Serial(ports[1], 9600)

    #send the command
    ser.write((str(command) + "\n").encode())
    ser2.write((str(command) + "\n").encode())

    #interpret the command
    if(command == 1):
        #use this command to play the video and fill in the file name
        subprocess.call(["./shell_script_to_call"])

    command = input("Enter another command: ")
```

Comment: Its omxplayer - not oxmplayer ! It should be pre-installed on Raspbian.

Comment: You are right! I feel so dumb and thought I was losing my mind seeing everyone say it came preinstalled but not being able to get it to work I'm going to spend a bit more time to trying to figure this out. Hopefully having access to omxplayer makes this possible, using SSH to control this pi makes things quite a bit more difficult too.

Comment: You realise you can't play a video over ssh?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean, I managed to accomplish what I wanted. I did this by opening a subprocess to call another script that plays a video on my display, all from my phone using Termius. However, I'm pretty new to Python, linux, and programming in general so I assume you know more than I do. Thanks for the correction on omxplayer, I'm either dumb or dyslexic!